# C# In codebehind, how reference public variable in another class within the same namespace?

Tags: c#, class, global-variables

I have a code behind that has two classes within the same namespace.  I'd like to reference the first classes public variables from the second class in the namespace.  I know I could obviously pass the variables, but I'd like to know if there is a way to reference them.

```
namespace CADE.results
{
    public partial class benchmark : BasePage
    {
        public string numAnswers = "";   <-- like to reference this from GetScore()

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BenchmarkAdd bma = new BenchmarkAdd();
            bma.GetScore();
        }
    }


    public class BenchmarkAdd
    {
        public BenchmarkAdd() 
        { 
        }
        public void GetScore() 
        {
            benchmark.numAnswers++;    <-- would like to reference public var here
        }
    }

}
```

I thought just benchmark.numAnswers would work but it doesn't.  Is it possible to reference numAnswers from the BenchmarkAdd class?

Comment: Can you please fix the code to the extend your question will be the only problem in [mcve]?

Comment: What is `GetScore()` inside `BenchmarkAdd()`? Typo?

Comment: The structure of your classes doesn't make sense. What is the purpose of `BenchmarkAdd` class? Looks like you should just put `GetScore` inside the `System.Web.UI.Page` class.

Comment: As I said, I thought I could reference numAnswers from the "benchmark" class using its name.  GetScore() is a function within the BenchmarkAdd class that will do work.  It's not important what work it's doing, I simply wanted to know if numAnswers could be reference within it.

Comment: You are declaring a method within the constructor.... huh?

Comment: Insane... sorry, mistake in making pseudo code.  Edited

Comment: So, are you asking for anything different than creating an instance of benchmark and then accessing numAnswers? I would think you knew that.

Comment: Insane, that's it... but I can't access numAnswers from inside GetScore... that's what I'm asking if it's possible to do without passing numAnswers to GetScore.  benchmark.numAnswers is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to reference the first classes public variables from the second class in the namespace.

Well `numAnswers` is an instance variable, so `GetScore()` isn't going to know which instance to update.

The only way this can be done (without passing your `Page` instance, or passing `numAnswers` using `ref`) is to make `numAnswers` `static`:

```
public static string numAnswers = "";
```

Which you could then update in `GetScore()`:

```
public void GetScore() 
{
    CADE.results.benchmark.numAnswers++;
}
```

However, the effect of making this `static` is that each `benchmark` instance no longer has it's own `numAnswers` field; there would be only one copy of the field which would instead belong to the type itself.

Comment: D'oh... so easy.  That works!... and I do want only one copy of the field, so the answer is perfect.